# Redirect 301 - Google still cache old version website

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect, technical-seo, google-cache

I have website `example.com` (portal) and `example.com/shop/` (shop).
I changed the shop to a subdomain `shop.example.com` and 301 redirected all URLs from `example.com/shop/` to `shop.example.com`.

That was over a year ago. Google still has copies of my old directory page `example.com/shop/` with the current version from April this year. Where could the problem be? Despite the 301 redirects there are two versions of the page in Google: `example.com/shop/` and `shop.example.com`. Where should I look for the cause?

The 301 redirects are implemented correctly.

Comment: Can Google crawl the redirect or is it blocked by robots.txt?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the live URLs in Google Search Console?

Comment: Have you changed all the links on your site to the new subdomain instead of linking to the old URL?

Comment: If you have an XML sitemap, have you updated it to have only the new URLs in it?